# How do Angular templates work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I've been looking into using Angular, and am interested in how the templating works. Having tried search for this answer most results are about *`How to use Angular templates`*.

In a few of the articles I've read, it is claimed that angular does more than just string manipulation, but none of these says what it is actually doing above something like Handlebars.

The method that I use instead of string insertion is `document.createElement('tagName')` *`element`*`.appendChild()`.

Though surely it is fairly convoluted to parse these templates from near-HTML into `createElement` - `appendChild` manipulation.

But then I wonder how these coveted data-bindings that I keep reading about work. When in pure javascript I would use an event listener and just inject or append-textNode into a `<span>`

Comment: [This might help](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates)

Comment: @RamblinRose That is *how to* not *how it works*

Comment: http://daginge.com/technology/2014/03/04/understanding-template-compiling-in-angularjs/

Comment: @MikeFeltman That still doesn't explain the underlying mechanics

Comment: It's open source. Knock yourself out. Is there a particular problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @MikeFeltman 33,375 lines of code 482 instances of `templat` (sans `e` or `ing`). Not an easy codebase just to find out how something works